# How to return an array of objects from a collection, to state in react using meteor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm using react-select to collect tags that has been defined in a mongodb collection called `tags`, I need to insert my tags in array `options[]` ins state the same way it's in `staticOptions[]`.

**issue:** `console.log(name)` in my `handleOptions()` is logging only the first item in for loop only.

**Question:** How to return an array of objects from `tags` collection to `this.state.options` to be just like the `staticOptions`?

```
//-------create class: Addgifts-----
export default class Addgifts extends Component{
constructor(){
super()
this.state={
  value: [],
  options: [],
  staticOptions: [{ label: 'Chocolate', value: 'chocolate' },
            { label: 'Vanilla', value: 'vanilla' },
            { label: 'Strawberry', value: 'strawberry' },
          ]
 }
}

//-------Handle options--------
handleOptions(){
let KeyWords = this.props.tags;
for (i=0 ; i<KeyWords.length ; i++){
  return KeyWords[i].map.name((names)=>{
    console.log(name);
    return(
       this.state.options.push({label:{name},value:{name}});
      )
    }
  });
 }
}

//-----Select Change----
handleSelectChange (value) {
    console.log('You\'ve selected:', value);
this.setState({
    value
 });
}

//-----Select package----
<div>
 <Select
 multi={true}
 value={this.state.value}
 placeholder="Select all KeyWord(s)"
 options={this.handleOptions()}
 onChange={this.handleSelectChange.bind(this)} />
</div>

//-----subscribing tags from mongodb----
Addgifts.propTypes={tags: PropTypes.array.isRequired,};
export default createContainer(()=>{
Meteor.subscribe('tags');
return {gifts: Gifts.find({},{sort:{name:-1}}).fetch(),};
},Addgifts);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should transfer the data in props to state in componentDidMount() or (componentWillReceiveProps() if the props are getting updated with new props) and directly pass options to the select box. Doing it in handleOptions() is not a good idea.

Second, the i believe the logic inside handleOptions is not correct for iterating over an array of object.

Do something like this.

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  var options = [];
  for (i=0 ; i<this.props.tags.length ; i++){
    var name = this.props.tags[i].name;
    console.log(name);
    options.push({label:name, value: name});
  }
  this.setState({options: options});
},

render: function() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Select
      multi={true}
      value={this.state.value}
      placeholder="Select all KeyWord(s)"
      options={this.state.options}
      onChange={this.handleSelectChange.bind(this)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```